# Bison shift/reduce conflict ambigous

Tags: bison, shift-reduce-conflict

when i try to use$ bison --output=calcy.c -d calc.y
i get this msg:

`calc.y: conflicts: 2 shift/reduce`

and this is my code

```
program:DEBUT
     corps   
      FIN 
  ;
corps:liste_declaration
      liste_instruction
  ;
liste_declaration:
| declaration";"liste_declaration
;
declaration: ENTIER IDENTIFICATEUR
;
liste_instruction:
|instruction";"liste_instruction
;
instruction: IDENTIFICATEUR"="expression
| DEBUT liste_instruction FIN
| SI expression 
ALORS instruction
SINON instruction
| SI expression ALORS instruction
| TANTQUE expression FAIRE instruction
| ECRIRE liste_argument
| LIRE IDENTIFICATEUR
;
liste_argument:
| expression 
| expression ";"liste_argument
;
expression:expression"<"expression_simple
|expression">"expression_simple
|expression"=="expression_simple
|expression"!="expression_simple
|expression"<="expression_simple
|expression">="expression_simple
|expression_simple
;
expression_simple:expression_simple"+"terme
|expression_simple"-"terme
|"("expression_simple")"
|terme
|"-"terme
;
terme:terme"*"facteur
|terme"/"facteur
|terme"^"facteur
|facteur
;
facteur:IDENTIFICATEUR|NOMBRE
;
```

I searched a lot and I think it's caused by ambiguity, but I cant find where it is.

I used the option `-v` as Mr Chris Dodd suggested in a comment, and I got this in my .output file.nv

```
    Grammar

        0 $accept: program $end

        1 program: DEBUT corps FIN

        2 corps: liste_declaration liste_instruction

        3 liste_declaration: /* empty */
        4                  | declaration ";" liste_declaration

        5 declaration: ENTIER IDENTIFICATEUR

        6 liste_instruction: /* empty */
        7                  | instruction ";" liste_instruction

        8 instruction: IDENTIFICATEUR "=" expression
        9            | DEBUT liste_instruction FIN
       10            | SI expression ALORS instruction SINON instruction
       11            | SI expression ALORS instruction
       12            | TANTQUE expression FAIRE instruction
       13            | ECRIRE liste_argument
       14            | LIRE IDENTIFICATEUR

       15 liste_argument: /* empty */
       16               | expression
       17               | expression ";" liste_argument

       18 expression: expression "<" expression_simple
       19           | expression ">" expression_simple
       20           | expression "==" expression_simple
       21           | expression "!=" expression_simple
       22           | expression "<=" expression_simple
       23           | expression ">=" expression_simple
       24           | expression_simple

       25 expression_simple: expression_simple "+" terme
       26                  | expression_simple "-" terme
       27                  | terme

       28 terme: terme "*" facteur
       29      | terme "/" facteur
       30      | facteur

       31 facteur: X "^" facteur
       32        | X

       33 X: "(" expression_simple ")"
       34  | "-" X
       35  | IDENTIFICATEUR
       36  | NOMBRE
```

These are the states with conflicts:

```
    state 33

       16 liste_argument: expression .
       17               | expression . ";" liste_argument
       18 expression: expression . "<" expression_simple
       19           | expression . ">" expression_simple
       20           | expression . "==" expression_simple
       21           | expression . "!=" expression_simple
       22           | expression . "<=" expression_simple
       23           | expression . ">=" expression_simple

        ";"   shift, and go to state 53
        "<"   shift, and go to state 40
        ">"   shift, and go to state 41
        "=="  shift, and go to state 42
        "!="  shift, and go to state 43
        "<="  shift, and go to state 44
        ">="  shift, and go to state 45

        ";"       [reduce using rule 16 (liste_argument)]
        $default  reduce using rule 16 (liste_argument)
```

```
    state 56

       10 instruction: SI expression ALORS instruction . SINON instruction
       11            | SI expression ALORS instruction .

        SINON  shift, and go to state 70

        SINON     [reduce using rule 11 (instruction)]
        $default  reduce using rule 11 (instruction)
```

Comment: By the way, there is no extra cost for using whitespace in your grammar. Your readers will appreciate the gesture.

Comment: Use bison's `-v` option to get a calc.output file showing the generated states and conflicts.  That will then show you which rules/symbols are in conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two shift-reduce conflicts, which have completely different causes. Only one is strictly speaking an ambiguity; ironically, it is the easier one to fix.

#### 1. The ambiguity: *dangling else*

One is the classic ["dangling-else"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) ambiguity (which Wikipedia's French-language page suggests might be translated as [*sinon pendant*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else). This ambiguity is easy to fix or workaround:

- Add `%expect 1` to your bison file. (Bison lets you put this declaration anywhere in the file, so it would be reasonable to put it just before or just after the `instruction` definition. But in other yacc dialects, you'd need to put it before the first `%%` in the file.)

  All this does is to tell the parser generator to suppress the warning message if there is exactly one shift-reduce conflict. The conflict will be resolved using the default resolution, which is to prefer to shift the `SINON` token. As it happens, this is exactly what you want in this case, which is why it is the default resolution.
- Use precedence declarations to make shifting `SINON` preferable to reducing an `ALORS` production. (Productions are named after the *last* terminal in the production, not the first one.)

  This has precisely the same effect as the first one, but in a slightly more robust way since it is not dependent on the total count of shift-reduce conflicts.
- Rewrite the grammar to make `SI ... ALORS ... SINON` unambiguous.

  This is arguably the best solution, but it is a lot more work since it forces you to consider all compound statements which can end with a statement. In your case, there are just two -- SI and TANTQUE -- but you might want to add other looping constructs later. You can find sample code in the Wikipedia page (which is currently quite a mess, so it may not be the best place to look at the moment) or by searching for "dangling else" and using some discretion.

#### 2. The just barely non-ambiguity: double meaning of `;`

The other shift-reduce conflict is due to the fact that you use `;` both to separate statements and to separate arguments in a `ECRIRE` statement. That means that when the parser reaches a `;` while analysing an `ECRIRE` statement, it cannot know whether or not the `;` terminates the statement or not. If it's the end of the statement, the parser must reduce `ECRIRE liste_argument` to `instruction`; otherwise, it needs to shift the `;` in order to add another `expression` to the `liste_argument`.

This is not, strictly speaking, ambiguous, because your language requires all statements to start with a keyword or with `IDENTIFICATEUR "="`, and neither of these can be the start of an expression. So the parser would only need to look at a maximum of three symbols (including the `;`) in order to know for sure whether what comes next is an expression or a statement.

That fact doesn't help you much, since bison parsers will normally only look at the next symbol, which is the `;`, and must make reduction decisions based on that. So even though the grammar is not ambiguous -- every valid program can only be parsed in one way -- the bison parser cannot know which parse to use at the moment it needs to know.

It is possible to fix this, because it is possible to write a one-symbol lookahead grammar for any language which can be parsed with bounded lookahead. But it's tedious and the resulting grammars are big, clunky, and hard to read.

Also, it may be the case that some future addition to your language will make `ECRIRE` statements actually ambiguous. For example, you do not (currently) allow function calls. But at some point, you may well want to add functions to your language, and when you do so you might want to make it possible to call a function without assigning its return value to any variable. That would normally be done by just adding `expression` to the list of possible `instruction`s, but as soon as you do that, the semicolon in `ECRIRE` becomes ambiguous, since it could be followed by an expression to be printed, or by an expression to be executed as the next statement.

If you're certain that this will never be an issue and that the grammar really will be unambiguous, as it is now, you could fix the problem by telling bison to produce a [`%glr-parser`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Generalized-LR-Parsing). Although that complicates bison's job, it doesn't have much impact on you: you can continue to use the grammar in the same way, as long as it is not ambiguous.

But if you think you might want to introduce expression statements at some point, you might be better off changing the syntax of your language. If you used `,` to separate arguments to `ECRIRE` and reserved `;` to separate statements (which is a pretty common approach), then the two delimiters will not interfere with each other and the grammar will be automatically unambiguous.